# Way to select from multi list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list.Want to compare them

```
foreach (SQLFrameWorkEntity item in oListParent)
{
   foreach (SQLFrameWorkEntity item2 in oList)
   {
      if (item.TableNumber == item2.ReferenceNumber 
          && item.TableNumber!=item2.TableNumber)
      {
           oListReferenceTable.Add(item2);
      }
   }
}
```

I try to achieve this result in linq,but bellow syntax does not give me required output.

```
var r = oListParent.Select(p => 
                      oList.Select(q => q.ReferenceNumber == p.TableNumber))
                   .ToList();
```

help me to **correction** the above linq syntax to achieve the required output
If have query plz ask.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
var r = oList.Where(x => oListParent.Any(y => y.TableNumber == x.ReferenceNumber &&
                                              y.TableNumber != x.TableNumber))
             .ToList()
```

Comment: twoflower thank you very much.it's working.will you plz tell me why i get bool list.

Comment: @shamim: Each item of your Select is a boolean condition: Select(q => `q.ReferenceNumber == p.TableNumber)`)

Comment: @shamim That's because `bool` is what your inner `Select` is giving back for each `q`: boolean condition `q.ReferenceNumber == p.TableNumber`. So at the end you end up with `List` of `IEnumerable<bool>`

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from item in oListParent 
             join item2 in oList on item.TableNumber equals item2.ReferenceNumber
             where item.TableNumber != item2.TableNumber
             select item2;
```